# Android: Change splash screen based on language

Tags: android, image, splash-screen

I have an app with different splash screen.. One for italian language and one for the english one. How can I set my app to choose the correct image based on system language?

Answer (score 7):

You can put different drawables and layouts in different resource directories such as:

```
res/drawable-en/
res/drawable-it/
res/layout-en/
res/layout-it/
```

`en` for english and `it` for italian. It might be best to keep the "default" resources in the standard directories with no language specifier.

If you name the actual files inside those directories as the same name, then the system will automatically pick the correct file depending on the users locale.

See [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

you can use multiple resource folders and it will load images based on device locale/config

having the folders with prefix will automatically detect/load for local

eg

```
res/layout-en/
res/layout-it/
```