# if user’s selected language is EN – show English splash screen, if FR – show French splash screen

Tags: splash-screen

Is it possible dynamically (according to user selected language on mobile device) to change splash screen when application starts (if user’s selected language is EN – show English splash screen, if FR – show French splash screen?

(Its a project, which is about to wrap web app into hybrid app using MobileFirst Platform.)

Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the answer is Yes, since in MobileFirst Platform the Hybrid application still generates a native project, so any native solution applies as well.

See these existing solutions:

- [Android: Change splash screen based on language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822870/android-change-splash-screen-based-on-language)
- [IOS: launch image multiple language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language)

Comment: The Hybrid app in MobileFirst is *still a native app*, the above is the configuration that you should apply to your generated native project.