# Cordova App How do i show splash screens based on user's phone?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

We have a cordova app where we have added images with various dimensions . Please see below

[image]

Currently we have the splash screen common for all languages . How do i show different splash screens for different languages ?

Comment: That ionic takes care of itself, according to the screen resolution of the device, the same way android takes care of images when you put them is their respective resolution folder

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What i need is splash screen to shown based on user's phone language that is Danish user - Danish splash screen , English user - English splash screen , Swedish user- Swedish splash screen

Comment: that is something I have never come across in Ionic but maybe you can try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14822895/3521116 ans i.e. make `drawable-land-xhdpi` in res in ionic to `drawable-en-land-xhdpi` and lets say for italian `drawable-it-land-xhdpi` see if that works